# How to Schedule long running Task in ASP.NET on Button CLick

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks

How to Schedule long running Task in ASP.NET on Button Click

I want to insert 100 million record in database, and there will be many files on regular basis
I will upload the csv file through FileUpload, and click on Button so  in back end it should call some scheduler(some file) which will insert all record in database and inform once its complete.

Comment: "crore" is not a common English term. You should probably say "10 million" or "10,000,000".

Comment: .let me know something do you want to make a schedule once user has click the button or do you want to import the file as background process once user click the button? Please clear me.

Comment: i want to make schedule once user has clicked a button.
flow is: user uploads file with 10 million records, internally my program should call scheduler to perform database insert, once it is done, scheduler should inform my client.